# Why Sentry prevents creating the build in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js13, sentry

I have integrated Sentry for tracking the errors in the production in NextJS.

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/?original_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fsentry.io%2F) and the integration went well.

However when I ran `npm run build` I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you missed you sentry auth token in the CI where the build is executed?